# Syntax error' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) on Woocommerce Hook

Tags: woocommerce

I meet this error message in this function and i don't see any problem with characters.

syntax error, unexpected ''cfwc_save_cus' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

```
function cfwc_save_custom_field( $post_id ) {
 $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
 $title = isset( $_POST['custom_description'] ) ? $_POST['custom_description'] : '';
 $product->update_meta_data( 'custom_description', sanitize_text_field( $title ) );
 $product->save();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'cfwc_save_custom_field' );
```

Comment: Please make sure the double quotes and quotes are matching properly. If there are double quotes in the String they can be escaped using the operator as " (quotes).

Comment: Do you mean here $_POST['custom_description']